# Error when cloning repo in github actions: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address

Tags: git, github, continuous-integration, github-actions, git-clone

I have a repository secret named `FOO_SECRET` (its a Personal Access Token with fine grained scopes)

The following workflow step step fails however

```
      - name: clone repo
        working-directory: /tmp
        shell: bash
        run: |
          git clone \
            --branch ${{ env.DEFAULT_BRANCH }} \
            --single-branch \
              https://${{ secrets.FOO_SECRET }}@${{ matrix.repository }}
```

The error is the following

```
fatal: could not read Password for 'https://***@github.com': No such device or address
```

Why is that?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much safer solution than adding the token to the clone URL or the global git config is to pass the token as an environment variable and register a very rudimentary credential helper:

```
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Setup git
        run: |
          git config --global user.email $env:GIT_EMAIL
          git config --global user.name $env:GIT_USER
          git config --global credential.helper "!f() { echo \`"username=`${GIT_USER}`npassword=`${GIT_PASS}\`"; }; f"
        shell: pwsh
        env:
          GIT_USER: "jessehouwing"
          GIT_EMAIL: "jesse.houwing@gmail.com"
          GIT_PASS: ${{ secrets.PUSHTOKEN }}
```

That way the password is never stored on disk and it can be selectively passed to the env of any step that needs access to the token.

You can also use the `actions/checkout@v4` task and pass in an alternative token:

```
uses: actions/checkout@v4
  with:

    # The branch, tag or SHA to checkout. When checking out the repository that
    # triggered a workflow, this defaults to the reference or SHA for that event.
    # Otherwise, uses the default branch.
    ref: ${{ env.DEFAULT_BRANCH }}

    # Personal access token (PAT) used to fetch the repository. The PAT is configured
    # with the local git config, which enables your scripts to run authenticated git
    # commands. The post-job step removes the PAT.
    #
    # We recommend using a service account with the least permissions necessary. Also
    # when generating a new PAT, select the least scopes necessary.
    #
    # [Learn more about creating and using encrypted secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/automating-your-workflow-with-github-actions/creating-and-using-encrypted-secrets)
    #
    # Default: ${{ github.token }}
    token: ${{ secrets.FOO_SECRET }}
    repository: ${{ matrix.repository }}
```

Answer (score -1):

```bash
git clone https://x-access-token:<TOKEN-HERE>@github.com/owner/repo.git
```

[source](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/apps/creating-github-apps/authenticating-with-a-github-app/authenticating-as-a-github-app-installation#about-authentication-as-a-github-app-installation): attention to `x-access-token`, that is the essential part